# Proving Termination of Function in Coq

Tags: recursion, coq, termination

I am having trouble proving termination of the following function:

```
Fixpoint norm_union u v : regex :=
  match u, v with
  | Empty    , v         => v
  | u        , Empty     => u
  | Union u v, w         => norm_union u (norm_union v w)
  | u        , Union v w => if eq_regex_dec u v
                            then Union v w
                            else if le_regex u v
                                 then Union u (Union v w)
                                 else Union v (norm_union u w)
  | u        , v         => if eq_regex_dec u v
                            then u
                            else if le_regex u v
                                 then Union u v
                                 else Union v u
  end.
```

where `regex` is the type of regular expressions and `le_regex` implements a total ordering on regular expressions. The source is page five of [this](http://www21.in.tum.de/~krauss/papers/rexp.pdf) document. The function occurs as part of a normalization function for regular expressions (formalized in Isabelle/HOL). The `le_regex` function is adapted from the same paper. I am using `ascii` to avoid parameterizing `regex` by a decidable total ordering (and want to extract the program).

```
Inductive regex : Set :=
  | Empty   : regex
  | Epsilon : regex
  | Symbol  : ascii -> regex
  | Union   : regex -> regex -> regex
  | Concat  : regex -> regex -> regex
  | Star    : regex -> regex.

Lemma eq_regex_dec : forall u v : regex, {u = v} + {u <> v}.
Proof. decide equality; apply ascii_dec. Defined.

Fixpoint le_regex u v : bool :=
  match u, v with
  | Empty       , _            => true
  | _           , Empty        => false
  | Epsilon     , _            => true
  | _           , Epsilon      => false
  | Symbol a    , Symbol b     => nat_of_ascii a <=? nat_of_ascii b
  | Symbol _    , _            => true
  | _           , Symbol _     => false
  | Star u      , Star v       => le_regex u v
  | Star u      , _            => true
  | _           , Star v       => false
  | Union u1 u2 , Union v1 v2  => if eq_regex_dec u1 v1
                                  then le_regex u2 v2
                                  else le_regex u1 v1
  | Union _ _   , _            => true
  | _           , Union _ _    => false
  | Concat u1 u2, Concat v1 v2 => if eq_regex_dec u1 v1
                                  then le_regex u2 v2
                                  else le_regex u1 v1
  end.
```

I think the correct approach is to define a decreasing measure and use `Program Fixpoint` to prove termination. However, I'm having trouble coming up with the correct measure (attempts based on the number of operators have been unsuccessful). I have tried factoring the work into separate functions, but ran into similar problems. Any help would be appreciated, or hints pointing in the right direction.

Comment: Please add the definition of type regex in Coq syntax as part of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After an extra day of work, I now have a more complete answer to this question.  It is still visible at [this link](https://github.com/ybertot/norm_union_example).  This solution deserves a few comments.

First, I am using a function constructor called `Fix` (the long name is `Coq.Init.Wf.Fix`.  This is a higher order function that can be used to define functions by well-founded recursion.  I need a well founded order for this, this order is called `order`.  Well founded orders were studied intensively in the early 2000s and they are still at the foundation of the `Program Fixpoint` command.

Second, the code you wrote performs case analyses on two values of type `regex` simultaneously, so this leads to 36 cases (a bit less, because there is no case analysis on the second argument when the first one is `Empty`).  You don't see the 36 cases in your code, because several constructors are covered by the same rule where the pattern is just a variable.  To avoid this multiplication of cases, I devised a specific inductive type for
the case analyses.  I called this specific type `arT`.  Then I define a function `ar` that maps any element of type `regex` to the corresponding element of `arT`.  The type `arT` has three constructors instead of six, so pattern maching expressions will contain much less code and proofs will be less verbose.

Then I proceeded to define `norm_union` using `Fix`.  As usual in Coq (and in most theorem provers, including Isabelle), the language of
recursive definitions ensures that recursive functions always terminate.  In this case, this is done by imposing that recursive calls only happen on arguments that are *smaller* than the function's input.  In this case, this is done by describing the body of the recursive function by a function that takes as first argument the initial input and as second argument the function that will be used to represent the recursive calls.  The name of this function is `norm_union_F` and its type is as follows:

```
forall p : regex * regex,
   forall g : (forall p', order p' p -> 
            {r : regex | size_regex r <= size_2regex p'}), 
    {r : regex | size_regex r <= size_2regex p}
```

In this type description, the name of the function used to represent recursive calls is `g` and we see that the type of `g` imposes that it can only be used on pairs of `regex` terms that are smaller than the initial argument `p` for the order named `order`.  In this type description, we also see I chose to express that the returned type of the recursive calls is not `regex` but `{r : regex | size_regex r <= size_2regex p'}`.  This is because we have to handle *nested recursion*, where outputs of recursive calls will be used as inputs of other recursive calls.  **This is the main trick of this answer**.

Then we have the body of the `norm_union_F` function:

```
Definition norm_union_F : forall p : regex * regex,
   forall g : (forall p', order p' p -> 
                {r : regex | size_regex r <= size_2regex p'}), 
    {r : regex | size_regex r <= size_2regex p} :=
 fun p norm_union =>
   match ar (fst p) with
     arE _ eq1 => exist _ (snd p) (th1 p)
   | arU _ u v eq1 =>
     match ar (snd p) with
       arE _ eq2 => exist _ (Union u v) (th2' _ _ _ eq1)
     | _ => exist _ (proj1_sig 
             (norm_union (u, 
                 proj1_sig (norm_union (v, snd p) 
                 (th3' _ _ _ eq1)))
                 (th4' _ _ _ eq1 (th3' _ _ _ eq1) 
                   (proj1_sig (norm_union (v, snd p) (th3' _ _ _ eq1)))
                   _))) 
             (th5' _ _ _ eq1 
                 (proj1_sig (norm_union (v, snd p)
                               (th3' _ _ _ eq1)))
                 (proj2_sig (norm_union (v, snd p)
                               (th3' _ _ _ eq1)))
                 (proj1_sig
                     (norm_union 
                          (u, proj1_sig (norm_union (v, snd p)
                                          (th3' _ _ _ eq1)))
                   (th4' _ _ _ eq1 (th3' _ _ _ eq1) 
                   (proj1_sig (norm_union (v, snd p) (th3' _ _ _ eq1)))
                   (proj2_sig (norm_union (v, snd p) (th3' _ _ _ eq1))))))
                 (proj2_sig
                     (norm_union 
                          (u, proj1_sig (norm_union (v, snd p)
                                          (th3' _ _ _ eq1)))
                   (th4' _ _ _ eq1 (th3' _ _ _ eq1) 
                   (proj1_sig (norm_union (v, snd p) (th3' _ _ _ eq1)))
                   (proj2_sig (norm_union (v, snd p) (th3' _ _ _ eq1)))))))
     end
   | arO _ d1 d2 =>
     match ar (snd p) with
       arE _ eq2 => exist _ (fst p) (th11' _)
     | arU _ v w eq2 =>
       if eq_regex_dec (fst p) v then
          exist _ (Union v w) (th7' _ _ _ eq2)
       else if le_regex (fst p) v then
         exist _ (Union (fst p) (Union v w)) (th8' _ _ _ eq2)
       else exist _ (Union v (proj1_sig (norm_union (fst p, w)
               (th9' _ _ _ eq2))))
               (th10' _ _ _ eq2
                 (proj1_sig (norm_union (fst p, w)
                       (th9' _ _ _ eq2)))
                 (proj2_sig (norm_union (fst p, w)
                       (th9' _ _ _ eq2))))
     | arO _ d1 d2 =>
       if eq_regex_dec (fst p) (snd p) then
         exist _ (fst p) (th11' _)
       else if le_regex (fst p) (snd p) then
         exist _ (Union (fst p) (snd p)) (th12' _)
       else exist _ (Union (snd p) (fst p)) (th13' _)
     end
   end.
```

In this code, all output values are within an `exist _`  context: not only do we produce the output value, but we also show that the size of this value is smaller than the combined size of the input pair of values.  More over, all recursive calls are within a `proj1_sig` context, so that we forget the size information at the moment of constructing the output value.  But also, all recursive calls, here represented by calls to the function named `norm_union` also have a proof that the input to the recursive call is indeed smaller than the initial input.  All the proofs are in [the complete development](https://github.com/ybertot/norm_union_example).

It would probably be possible to use tactics like `refine` to define `norm_union_F`, you are invited to explore.

Then we define the truly recursive function `norm_union_1`

```
Definition norm_union_1 : forall p : regex*regex,
  {x | size_regex x <= size_2regex p} :=
  Fix well_founded_order (fun p => {x | size_regex x <= size_2regex p})
  norm_union_F.
```

Note that the output of `norm_union_1` has type `{x | size_regex x <= size_2regex p}`.  This is not the type you asked for.  So we define a new function, which is really the one you want, simply by forgetting the logical information that the output has a size smaller than the input.

```
Definition norm_union u v : regex := proj1_sig (norm_union_1 (u, v)).
```

You might still doubt that this is the right function, the one you asked for.  To convince ourselves, we are going to prove a lemma that expresses exactly what you would have said in a definition.

We first prove the corresponding lemma for `norm_union_1`.  This relies on a theorem associated to the `Fix` function, name `Fix_eq`.  The proof that needs to be done is fairly routine (it always is, it could be done automatically, but I never came around to developing the automatic tool for that).

Then we finish with most interesting lemma, the one for `norm_union`.  Here is the statement:

```
Lemma norm_union_eqn u v :
  norm_union u v = 
  match u, v with
  | Empty    , v         => v
  | u        , Empty     => u
  | Union u v, w         => norm_union u (norm_union v w)
  | u        , Union v w => if eq_regex_dec u v
                            then Union v w
                            else if le_regex u v
                                 then Union u (Union v w)
                                 else Union v (norm_union u w)
  | u        , v         => if eq_regex_dec u v
                            then u
                            else if le_regex u v
                                 then Union u v
                                 else Union v u
  end.
```

Please note that the right-hand-side of this equation is exactly the code that you gave in your initial question (I simply copy-pasted it).  The proof of this final theorem is also fairly systematic.

Now, I made the effort of following exactly your request, but after the fact I discovered that there is a simple implementation of the same functionality, using three recursive functions.  The first one flattens binary trees of `Union` to make then look like list, and the other two sort these union with respect to the order `le_regex` while removing duplicates as soon as they are uncovered.  Such an implementation would workaround the need for nested recursion.

If you still want to stick to nested recursion and need to refer to the technique described here, it was first published in a paper by Balaa and Bertot at TPHOLs2000.  That paper is difficult to read because it was written at a time when Coq was using a different syntax.

Comment: I apologize for the belated response. This was incredible work I couldn't have completed the development without! Working through your solution carefully definitely improved my understanding of Coq.

Comment: It might be interesting to publish a more complete tutorial on based on this example, also illustrating the capabilities of other parts of Coq like `Program Fiixpoint` or `Equation` on the topic, in a perfect world this also would contain a description showing how to treat this problem in other provers, like Isabelle, Agda, or Lean.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is more complex than what is usually handled with a measure function, because you have a nested recursive call in the following line:

```
Union u v, w         => norm_union u (norm_union v w)  (* line 5 *)
```

I suggest that you should not return a value in type `regex`, but in type `{r : regex | size r < combined_size u v}` for suitable notions of `size` and `combined_size`.

After several hours of study on your problem, it also turns out that your recursion relies on lexical ordering of the arguments.  `norm_union v w` may well return `Union v w`, so you need that the argument pair `(u, Union v w)` is smaller than `(Union u v, w)`.
So if you really want to use a measure, you need the weight of the left-hand side to be larger than the weight of the right-hand side, and you need the measure of a component of a `Union` to be less than the measure of the whole.

Because of the lexical ordering nature, I chose to not use a measure but a well-founded order.  Also, I don't know `Program Fixpoint` well enough, so I developed a solution to your problem using another tool.  The solution I came up with can be seen [here on github](https://github.com/ybertot/norm_union_example).  At least this shows all the decrease conditions that need to be proved.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I encountered difficult goals when using measures and `Program Fixpoint` due to the nested recursion. I can define the function in the way you describe, but I'm a little unclear *how* I would use it. Is the idea to piggyback off the proposition (`size r < combined_size u v`) to define a measure? Or was the idea to use tactics to define a term with that type, and then obtain a function from it?